# Can't access SQLCMD on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 12.10, mssql

after install mssqlserver and when I try to run SQL command through the terminal I face this
issue

SQL Command

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Sa123456#'
```

error

> sqlcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, I have MSSQL-Tools and msodbcsql17 installed correctly, and it's working fine with VS Code.

[image]

Comment: What's the 12.10 tag for, the mssql version?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen didn't know but I removed this distribution and install 12.04 and it's working with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output says that you are missing a file: `libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Let's use the http://packages.ubuntu.com website to solve this mystery, and to discover if an Ubuntu package provides this missing file.

[image]

- On the Search bar at the top of the page, note that we're looking for the missing filename (`libodbc.so.2`) among *package contents* (not package *names*).

Sure enough, there it is: Try installing the `libobdc1` package, which includes that missing file.
`sudo apt install libobdc1`